# Проблема с подсветкой в WebStorm и invalid в подсказках

Tags: javascript, webstorm

Кто знает из-за чего некорректно отображает подсказки? Версия WebStorm 2017.2.6, через раз выбрасывает такую меню з invalid вместо нормальной, а иногда нормально, на скрине все видно. Кто знает с чем это связано? (Не взлом, бесплатна лицензия для студентов) так же и в 2018.2.6, 2018.3;

также (версии 2018.2.6, 2018.3) некорректная подсветка this и super, при изменении цвета ключевых слов, все редактируются как нужно но this и super цвет не меняет но жирность и курсив меняет. Эти слова есть в списке ключевых слов, почему так?

в 2017.2.6 подсветка работает нормально

настройки удалял и все равно такая фигня

Скрины: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRWoT.jpg

Ноут: hp ProBook 4530s

Comment: Попробуйте в меню выбрать `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Comment: к сожалению не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Это известная проблема, проголосуйте, пожалуйста, за [WEB-26259](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26259), чтобы получать уведомления об обновлениях

Comment: Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: никак:( на стороне пользователя она не решается. Можно вынести код в отдельный js файл (т.к. проблема специфична для embedded javascript)